# Boostrap 4 and JQuery with Angular 5 not found

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-cli, bootstrap-4, angular5

I'm a beginer on Angular 5 and I'm trying to use Bootstrap 4 and JQuery in my project, thing is, even I've imported it correctly in my angular-cli it doesn't work at all. Here is my code in my angular cli:

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.scss",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

And those folders actually exist, as I've previously installed them with npm in the root folder of my project. Any ideas of what may I being doing wrong? Thanks in advance! ^^

Comment: I will not recommand you to use them directly but to use : 

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

or:
https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap

You will have a better integration and less .js problem than trying to do it yourself.

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting?